Test Driven Development: how to make time external to code
In my C++ codebase I have a class PassiveBuzzer, which emulates in software the behavior of an Active Buzzer driven over a PWM Line. It can be configured with patterns, with a Period and DutyCycle like PWM Lines. The constructor takes a frequency at which it buzzes when it is "on". The constructor also takes an object of type Linux::PWM::Line, which is derived from an interface PWM::Line. Thus, I can easily mock that object in unit tests.
To turn the Passive Buzzer on and off, I essentially use timerfd (with a C++ wrapper class) at the moment.
However, this prevents me from nicely testing the behavior of my class, since the Timer is constructed inside the PassiveBuzzer class, and not passed to it.
I would like to be able to test the PassiveBuzzer class and have the results be deterministic (independent of system load and other factors).
What are common ways to allow deterministic testing of classes that depend on time to trigger behavior? How can I make time external to my class?

Assuming you are using dependency injection as a part of your inversion of control, you just need to pass in your test double timer.  I've found that dependency injection is a critical part of test-driven development, which is key to putting pressure on the developer to abide by most of the SOLID principles in their code.  (C++ is harder to do TDD than other OO languages, because of the lengthy code-compile-test turnaround.  Decoupling components into standalone and testable parts piecemeal is important. And no hidden dependencies.)

...since the Timer is constructed inside the PassiveBuzzer class, and not passed to it  That's an example of a hidden dependency.  Refactor the code to get rid of that hidden dependency, and pass in the timer to the class's constructor.

@Eljay I assume you mean inject an abstract baseclass (interface) to a timer. When unit testing I usuall make timers that do not time anything and I just can call "next tick" or "set time" on the fake timer I inject (making my unit test effectively time independent)

@PepijnKramer • Correct, that's the gist.  That's how I've done it with C++, and with C# (which is decidedly easier to do in C#).

I don't understand, class PassiveBuzzer, which emulates in software the behavior of an Active Buzzer.  I would expect class PassiveBuzzer to be related to a passive buzzer, not an active one.  You may want to make the state {active/passive} a part of a class Buzzer.  If you really want OOP, you could derive class ActiveBuzzer and class PassiveBuzzer from class Buzzer.  Having worked in embedded systems for many decades, having class PassiveBuzzer model an Active buzzer is definitely wrong and confusing.

@ThomasMatthews: the PassiveBuzzer class emulated the behavior of an ActiveBuzzer, but does so using software for the timing instead of using hardware PWM for the timing. They indeed both inherit from a base class Buzzer.

As Eljay and Pepijn Kramer rightfully mentioned, I should just pass the Timer as a constructor argument to the PassiveBuzzer class. Thanks!
